# SSH to RSP 0W via bluetooth

Tags: ssh, bluetooth, pi-zero

I'm starting a new project for my RSP 0W.
I wold like to SSH to it via bluetooth from my Mac (Big sur).
I already can SSH via wifi but for my project no wifi will be available.

I already tried numerous tutorials on the internet without success.
Has anyone an idea or already done this?

Comment: Why aren't you using WIFI like everyone else? Networking over BlueTooth is a very specialised subject and not for the faint hearted.

Comment: I want to use mi RBP in the wild where I don't have WIFI access.

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to create a local network with my laptop and ssh trough that? Let me know...

Comment: You can make the RPi into a "stand-alone" WiFi access point that is NOT connected to the public internet so only your laptop can connect to it. Read the docs on the Raspberry Pi website at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#setting-up-a-routed-wireless-access-point just don't do the bridged/routed part. 

There's also WiFi connnection sharing in Windows 11 https://www.howtogeek.com/753210/how-to-create-a-mobile-hotspot-on-windows-11/

Both of those options are easier than BlueTooth networking.

Comment: Your question is an interesting one, but I've regretfully voted to close it *because* it seems that [you've not done enough research](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); rather it seems you've had an idea, and posted here with no effort to answer the question yourself. We are all considered `contributors` here - meaning that adding **your** findings to the question is essential. [Maybe try this first?](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=SSH+over+Blutooth)

Comment: And when you [try that first](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=SSH+over+Blutooth), be sure to read far enough down to find [this link that may be of some interest](https://nano.dannyvacar.ca/post/2019-12-13-raspberry-pi-ssh-over-bluetooth/).

Comment: Otherwise use your hotspot, works also with iPhone. Just add the name and password to your wpa_supplicant.conf and for testing do not forget to turn off your wifi!